# is there a way to host console app and webapi in 1 application

Tags: .net, containers, asp.net-core-webapi, console-application

My scenario is: I am developing a console app to perform some work and writing "status" to DB, and a REST endpoint to read that "status" from Db. Trying to see possibility if I can do both at same application without blocking each other:

1. console app processing and update "status" in Db
2. WebApi is hosted and serve to read "status" from db

I am reading on GenericHost and BackgroundWorker in dotnet core. But not able to do WebApi Hosting and console app both at same time in BackgroundWorker.
Not sure if it's important: this app would be hosted in Docker.

Comment: Can you perform some work and writing "status" to DB in background service in your web api?

Comment: A webapi app is a kind of console app too. What's your needs about the console app ? from my point of view, a webapi app with background service can make the job.

Comment: so console app is doing heavy lifting, calling external services process data, save it to db. thinking from support point of view, if possible without maintaining another app and once in a day to see report status of processing.